# winrt autoupdate

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime

I have an out of browser app with silverlight.

If I switch to winrt can it automatically update like silverlight does or is it just like a WPF app.

Where can I learn about winRT as a cloud app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit an update to your immersive application to the store, people who have installed the application will be notified of the update and will have the ability to download the update.

It does not "automatically update", your customers choose whether or not to accept the update.

The Windows Runtime has several facilities baked in for cloud applications - there are APIs available for reading XML elements and for parsing JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment of WinRT apps is the same as the deployment of Windows Phone 7 apps.

The marketplace publishes the app and contains optional updates. The users are free to download (or not) an update.

It's not quite clear what you mean by "WinRT as a cloud app"; WinRT is an OS/API. Apps use WinRT to access system resources.

Your application can use the cloud to access data and functionality. The app could connect to the user's SkyDrive, access Live contacts and other data. the app could also connect to an Azure application to access cloud functionality/data.

[A good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464912.aspx)

[Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Connecting to the cloud](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/28/extending-quot-windows-8-quot-apps-to-the-cloud-with-skydrive.aspx)